# docker-compose / nginx / SPA

Tags: node.js, nginx, docker, docker-compose

I want to use docker-compose with two containers, a nginx and another one that have a node.js application. The node.js application is a Single Page Application and an API express server.

I want that nginx serves the static files from the SPA. The problem is that my app container compiles the SPA when it starts and then I do not have the files for the nginx container.

I do not want to create a data volume for it, as I want the "composed" environment to not depend on external state.

I think something on a transient volume (a volume that is started with docker-compose up) and then removed, but this feature seems to not exist.

Another way be to serve the static files by NFS in the app container and let nginx read them, but not sure about how good or bad would be this.

What's the best practice to run this environment?

Comment: Instead of mounting, why don't you define a new container derived from nginx and have static files copied in? If that is just a single server it sounds ok to do that, but usually it is better to store your static in S3 (AWS) or Cloud Storage (GCE) when in production.

Comment: I want to compile (npm / webpack) the SPA application when starting its container. So I do not see how to have the static files in the nginx container.

Comment: The container you are using compiles it during runtime perhaps because of development purposes only. You can make your compilation with build (likely to be grunt/gulp related) command specific to SPA by running that container temporarily with `--rm` option and without `-d`. Would that provide you some traction how to get your distribution in hand outside of docker? Then you can copy that dist into new nginx container in separate docker build before release (or upload to cloud storage). Makes sense to write a script for it.

Comment: Post your current compose file